# Passing Data to cell before map View Delegate call

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, annotations, android-mapview

I'm building a map view inside a collection view cell. My requirement is custom annotation view on that.

I tried to use view For annotation delegate. But I need to pass some data from view controller to cell to customize it.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? { 
let identifier = "Pin"
                var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)
                pinView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)

if let title = location?.title {
 pinView.title = title 
}
```

Some initialization like that

Here is code for creating cell in side cellForRow at indexPath :

```
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: 
CellID.mapViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MapViewCell
            cell.configureMapCell(location: location)
            return cell
```

I tried to pass data after cell initialized but it was nil. 
When I do that on view controller, I did it in viewWillAppear and it was fine. But in cell, I don't know how to do that before cell initialized.

UPDATE: PROBLEM SOLVED 
I need to add AnnotationView after location data passed to cell. When annotation added , delegate functions will call and it has location data.